# Vim find and replace everything after '=' until end of line ($)

Tags: regex, vim

I have a line of strings (10 to 20):

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
...
field20 = models.DateField()
```

How can I use Vim's find and replace to remove everything from the equal sign until the end of line, so the text turns into:

```
title
...
field20
```

I'm familiar with the visual select find and replace (:s/\%Vfoo/bar/g), so I'd like to do something like (:s/\%V< = until $>//g), but this is what I am unsure how to find in Vim:

```
 = until $
```

I looked at the vimregex wiki, and tried the following with no success:

```
:s/\%V = (.*?)$//g
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Are you looking for this:

```
:%s/=.*/
```

?

It's the same as

```
:%s/=.*//
```

but the ending / can be omitted. You don't need the `g` btw because the pattern *to the end of the line* can match just once.

If you also want to remove the whitespace before the `=` use:

```
:%s/[[:blank:]]*=.*/
```

---

Note: If you think `[[:blank:]]` is hard to type, you can use `\s` instead. Both stand for *space or tab*.

Comment: `\s` is a much shorter version of `[[:blank:]]`

Comment: `[[:blank:]]` on the other hand is more explicit and more painful to type. ;)

Comment: @sidyll `\s` is a short version of `[[:space:]]`. `[[:blank:]]` is a "short" version of `[\t<space>]`.

Comment: Indeed painful :) Regarding `\s` being `[[:space:]]`, not quite. Check the help. `[[:space:]]` includes CR, NL, form feed and vtab. `\s` is only space and tab, just like `[[:blank:]]`.

Comment: I was just checking it and now closed the browser tab. :) Looks I misread it. I'll check again later and change the post if you are right. (I assume you are)

Comment: Don't worry, no need to change the answer. But if eventually you decide to do so, please keep both versions then. Thanks! vimdoc on [\[:blank:\]](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#[:blank:]) and [whitespace](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#whitespace)

Comment: While we are on this, I should add that although `[:space:]` itself includes a newline, for Vi compatibility the collection `[]` does not include a newline unless prepended by `\_` or if it includes `\n` explicitly. So `[[:space:]]` in practice means every whitespace char _but_ a newline. And `\_[[:space:]]` means every whitespace char. Also, there is the `\_x` family which always adds a newline to a `\x`. Like `\_s` which means `\s` (space and tab) plus a newline.

Comment: Good to know that. Thanks!